# Improvement Over Chance for an Event Forecasting System

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance

Suppose I have a device that forecasts migraines.  It does so by reading electrocardiograms and sending the ECG through a machine learning model, which returns a 0/1 classification of whether or not a migraine will occur with in an hour.

How can I show that my forecasting model is better than a forecaster that works off chance?

I have a few key ideas, but I am struggling in a few places:

- My model spends x% of time before the migraine in warning, so the chance predictor spends x% in time of warning as well.  Then, I compare the sensitivities of both predictors.  This doesn't make full sense though ... how would a chance predictor even work?
- Perhaps comparison against a naive predictor could work? (https://academic.oup.com/brain/article/130/2/314/284154)

Definitely a difficult problem.  It's a unique question of significance: how do I prove my test/treatment/device works better than placebo/chance?

Answer (score 1):

A standard measure is a predictor's skill - correlation between prediction and truth. If you want to show significance calculate a p-value, which is standard in statistical libraries, e.g. [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html). You can also calculate the siginificance yourself, as follows:

Say you have $n$ patients. Denote the migraines vector $m \in \{0,1\}^n$ - this is your *ground truth*. Your prediction scheme generates another sequence $p \in \{0,1\}^n$ - a prediction for each patient. A random predictor returns $1$ with probability $q$ (the frequency of migraines, in your case). Generate $N$ such random prediction vectors (e.g. using [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.binomial.html)) and denote them $r^{(i)}, i=1,...,N$. For each, calculate $c_i := Corr(m, r^{(i)})$. Now, if $Corr(m, p)$ is bigger than (say) 95% of the $c_i$'s, you can say that your predictor is significantly better than a random guess with a p-value of 5%.